# Kernel Panic on New Laptop

Tags: boot, kernel, system-installation

I just bought a Lenovo Thinkpad X1 Carbon Ultrabook.  I ran Ubuntu 14.04 from a flash drive and it worked beautifully.  I then installed it and the install seemed to go well, but when I try and boot I get:

```
Kernel panic - not syncing: No working init found.  Try passing init= option to kernel.
```

Does anybody know how I can resolve this?  I know the OS is compatible because the Live version works great.

Here is all the relevant information:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/7405506/

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you install the bootloader to /dev/sda and not /dev/sda1.

Comment: +1, though if they tried boot-repair (see the comments at my answer), then that should have caught that particular possible error.

Answer (score 0):

That does not sound like the installation went correctly. I would first just try reinstalling. If that failed again, I'd try a reinstall with a relatively small /boot partition at the start of the disk.

It could also be worth going into the live USB again, and downloading and running boot-repair from there.

Comment: I did try reintsalling.  The first time I had used full disk encryption.  I thought maybe that was the problem, so I tried again without it, but no luck.  I'll give boot-repair a try.

Comment: The small boot partition idea might also help, it's normally not important these days, but it could still be affecting the ability to find the I init.

Comment: Any idea what a minimum boot size would be?  Is something like 100M too small or too big?  (I just did the default install so not sure at the moment what size Ubuntu picked.)

Comment: I have a separate boot partition for other reasons, and it (after adjusting for some weirdness I won't get into as unrelated) is about 500MB, though you could probably get by with as little as 250MB as long as you don't keep too many old kernels around after kernel updates (kernel updates are the only thing that add to the amount of space used significantly). The more I think about it though, the more unlikely to matter this seems on a modern machine. What happened when you tried boot-repair?

Comment: It said it repaired the partition, but I still get the same error.  I'll probably need to post some more information (boot repair creates a link), but I'm at work right now.  I'm worried I'm not going to be able to make this work, but it works perfectly from in Live boot, so whatever this problem is, it couldn't be that big, I wouldn't think.

Comment: So, here is all the info.  http://paste.ubuntu.com/7405506/

Comment: That all looks good to me, I'm afraid. It might be worth editing your question to include that link, rather than having it as a comment, to increase the odds that someone who can help sees it.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  Is there any chance of this getting a response once no longer on the front page?